# Setting base path dynamically through jquery/javascript?

Tags: html, backbone.js, base-path

Is there a way to dynamically change the content inside the  tag?, throught jquery or javascript?

I am not using php or any server side script. I am using backbone.js and hence i have a .html file.

I have come to a situation where i would need to type in base path.

Like

```
<base href="www.google.com" />
```

I have searched around and i havent got anywhere.

Probably this is not possible at all, but just wanted to check it here in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery. Here is jsFiddle I've made http://jsfiddle.net/uQVeN/

HTML:

```
<base href="www.google.com" />
<div id="valueBefore"></div>
<div id="valueAfter"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#valueBefore').text( $('base').attr('href') );
    $('base').attr('href','kjhsgdkjahgdjkahgdf');
    $('#valueAfter').text( $('base').attr('href') );
});
```

Will produce:

```
www.google.com
kjhsgdkjahgdjkahgdf
```